# Title for section in UITableView - remove text shadow?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, dropshadow

I have a grouped **UITableView** with black background color.
Thus the gray section headers with the white drop shadows are unreadable.
Next thing to know, the section height varies depending on language and section.

How to solve this the most easy way ?

If I implement `viewForHeaderInSection` I also need to implement `heightForHeaderInSection`, but the height varies (several sections with different title and different language => different text length/view height)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically determine the height of the cell, and set your label so that it autosizes itself.

Hope [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) link will be helpful to you.

All the best.

Comment: It's not about the cell, it's about the section header

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 6.1. This worked for me:

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[[UILabel appearance] setShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```